# Thread data sync when use AsyncCallback

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to C# async API. However I has problem of how to sync data in callback function and I can not find info in MSDN.

Imagine that there is a socket wrapper class use async manner to send and recv data:

```
class MySocket {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    void Recv() {
        _socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 4, 0, new AsyncCallback(RecvCallback), null);
    }
    private void RecvCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int n = _socket.EndReceive(ar);
        if(n == 0)
            // use this.buffer
    }
}
```

The `RecvCallback` might called in another thread which is not the thread call `BeginReceive`, so generally, before access `this`, it need lock an mutex or something else to sync with `BeginReceive`(of course it need lock the same mutex object also).

However in MSDN example, there is no need to lock. I notice that, the data which accessed both in async launcher and callback was communicated by IAsyncResult as callback parameter.

So the question is does .net lib do thread sync on IAsyncResult? Must I change above callback to:

```
private void RecvCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    MySocket this_is_this = (MySocket)ar.AsyncState;
    int n = this_is_this._socket.EndReceive(ar);
    if(n == 0)
        // use this_is_this.buffer
}
```

?

**UPDATE:**

I post this question due to C# or (.Net) has no doc about it memory model. And Socket API doc also have no words about it. In other languages like Java, Go, Cpp, I can know which condition make happen-before relationship. If there is no this kind relationship, user need to care the thread sync by itself.

I don't know why C# has few specification about that. I only can guess according to MSDN example. In MSDN example code, there is no lock manually made(so the sync action must be done somewhere by itself(.NET Framework)) but does it enforce user use the AsyncState? Seems not, but I am not sure

Comment: I suppose that there is no synchronization between threads in this example and we'd have to make sure that both threads are using the same object `buffer`. Lock is something else. It allows a thread to enter a critical section of code and make other threads wait until this particular thread exits it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have do some test to find out:

1. pure async function call will not do thread sync for user.

   ```
   public class main
   {
       struct SharedData
       {
           public int a;
           public int b;
       }
       static SharedData d = new SharedData();
       public void TestMethod()
       {
           if (d.a != d.b)
               Console.WriteLine(d.a+" " +d.b);
       }
       public void callback(System.IAsyncResult ar)
       {
           d.a -= 1;
           d.b -= 1;
       }
       static AsyncMethodCaller caller;
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           d.a = 99999999;
           d.b = 99999999;
           main a = new main();
           caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(a.TestMethod);
           while (true)
               caller.BeginInvoke(new System.AsyncCallback(a.callback), null);
       }
       public delegate void AsyncMethodCaller();
   }
   ```

In this example, shared object d soon will corrupted.

2. Above thing will not happen in Socket class async operations. I use same test way in Socket class BeginReceive and callback function, the sending data frequency is 1 millisecond, data payload is 0~10 number of int32. I run about 1 hour, no corruption happen. This should be the MSDN doc said Socket class is thread safety meaning. However, generally, thread safe class means this class's methods can be concurrent. But the point is will class's method concurrent with the callback function(not class's method)? Through my test, the answer is yes.
3. Access shared data by IAsyncResult can have the effect of thread sync

   ```
   public class main
   {
       struct SharedData
       {
           public int a;
           public int b;
       }
       static SharedData d = new SharedData();
       public void TestMethod()
       {
           if (d.a != d.b)
               Console.WriteLine(d.a+" " +d.b);
       }
       public void callback(System.IAsyncResult ar)
       {
           SharedData dd = (SharedData)ar.AsyncState;
           dd.a -= 1;
           dd.b -= 1;
       }
       static AsyncMethodCaller caller;
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           d.a = 99999999;
           d.b = 99999999;
           main a = new main();
           caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(a.TestMethod);
           while (true)
               caller.BeginInvoke(new System.AsyncCallback(a.callback), d);
       }
       public delegate void AsyncMethodCaller();
   }
   ```

   Unlike example 1, the corruption will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

> so generally, before access this, it need lock an mutex or something else to sync with BeginReceive

Accessing `this` does not cause any problem whatsoever in a multithreaded context. And in general, most read operations are thread-safe. You need synchronization when you start sharing mutable state between two threads.

So for instance, your code is perfectly fine:

```
class MySocket {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    void Recv() {
        _socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 4, 0, new AsyncCallback(RecvCallback), null);
    }
    private void RecvCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int n = _socket.EndReceive(ar);
        if(n == 0)
            // use this.buffer
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you were mutating some kind of state, you would need synchronization:

```
class MySocket {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    private int totalNumberOfBytes;
    void Recv() {
        _socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 4, 0, new AsyncCallback(RecvCallback), null);
    }
    private void RecvCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int n = _socket.EndReceive(ar);

        // Needs synchronization if multiple operations happen simultaneously
        totalNumberOfBytes += n; 

        if(n == 0)
            // use this.buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: From other language exp, the RecvCallback access this.buffer and the buffer is filled with by another thread, if there is no sync action, RecvCallback thread might can not see the "filling".

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, there are two aspects in this question: First, whether `this` inside `RecvCallback` is the same as inside `Recv`. Second, whether the call to `RecvCallback` is synchronized with the calling thread.

For the first point, one has to look how the `AsyncCallback` delegate is created from the method `RecvCallback`. According to [this blog entry](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html), a delegate by default encapsulates the instance from which it is created from in its `Target` property, which is then passed as the `this` parameter when calling the delegate. Hence, there is no need to extract the `AsyncState` as `this_is_this`.

For the second point: There is no automatic synchronization when the callback is called, as there is no synchronization context available. Hence, this synchronization has to be done manually inside the callback.

Comment: For the second point, MSDN examples are all no lock, so the sync action must done somewhere. The question is does the sync action has requirements? like what I said the user must use AsyncState to get the data

Comment: Do you mean the example in [Executing a Callback Method When an Asynchronous Call Completes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously)? Here, the synchronization is done implicitly inside `Console.WriteLine`, which is the only access to shared resources.